# two diagnosis within one year

Tags: sas

Hi I have the following dataset. I am trying to find id who have at least 2 dx(411 or 430) within one year (dx1-dx5) and keep them in the dataset, otherwise drop. For example output in this case would be keeping id 1 and 3

```
data stat480.temp2;
input id $ date $9. dx1 $ dx2 $ dx3 $ dx4 $ dx5 $;
datalines;
    1 1/1/2005 411 412 413 414 415 
    1 2/2/2005 411 412 413 414 415
    2 1/1/2006 411 412 413 418 419
    2 3/3/2006 420 421 422 423 424
    3 3/4/2007 430 440 450 460 470
    3 12/4/2006 430 510 520 530 560
;
run;
```

Comment: Do you only have two rows per id? If not it would be helpful to provide a complete example of what your data look like.

Comment: Hi superfluous, the database is very large, there could be 20+ rows per id as it spans over several years.

Comment: When you say "at least 2 dx (411 or 430)", do you mean that 411 can be followed by either 411 or 430, or that 411 must be followed by 411, and 430 by 430? Also, is it just fortuitous that all the dx's looked after are in column dx1 ?

Comment: Can there be more than one row per id-month?

Comment: Hi Dominic when I say at least 2dx meaning requiring the patient to have two diagnosis of a specific disease within one year which can be either 411 or 430 (assuming both defines the same disease) so any combination of the two 411 with 411, 411 with 430, or 430 with 430. For your last comment that they are in dx1, I didn't pay attention I was just trying to write a hypothetical scenario but they can be any place dx1-dx4

Answer (score 1):

I added a few extra rows to demonstrate that this works for more than two observations per year. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
data temp;
input id date $10. dx1 dx2 dx3 dx4 dx5;
datalines;
    1 01/01/2005 411 412 413 414 415 
    1 02/02/2005 411 412 413 414 415
    2 01/01/2006 411 412 413 418 419
    2 03/03/2006 420 421 422 423 424
    3 12/04/2006 430 510 520 530 560
    3 03/04/2007 430 440 450 460 470
    3 12/04/2007 430 510 520 530 560
    3 12/05/2007 430 510 520 530 560
    3 03/04/2008 411 440 450 460 470
;
run;
```

First, convert each row's date variable into a numeric format, and concatenate its dx variables (to more easily compare dx1 with dx4, for example):

```
data temp2;
    set temp;
    date_num = day(input(trim(date), mmddyy10.)) + 
        month(input(trim(date), mmddyy10.)) * 12 + year(input(trim(date), mmddyy10.)) * 365;
    all_dx = catx(', ', dx1, dx2, dx3, dx4, dx5);
run;
```

Second, join this dataset to itself such that every observation is compared to every other observation within a year of it:

```
proc sql;
    create table temp3 as select distinct
        a.*, b.date_num as date_num2, b.all_dx as all_dx2
        from temp2 as a
        left join temp2 as b
        on a.id = b.id and (b.date_num - 365) < a.date_num <= (b.date_num - 1);
quit;
```

Subset based on the 411 and 430 criteria:

```
data temp4;
    set temp3 (where = (
        (index(all_dx, "411") or index(all_dx, "430")) and
        (index(all_dx2, "411") or index(all_dx2, "430"))));
run;
```

Select distinct IDs remaining:

```
proc sql;
    create table temp5 as select distinct id from temp4;
quit;
```

Yielding the dataset:

```
1
3
```

Comment: Your code will yield incorrect results if there are multiple observations of the same patient on different days of the same month. Your code is written such that two observations must be at least one month apart in order for them to be joined together. Depending on what the actual data looks like, I think it would be advantageous to replace the month_year variable by a day_month_year variable, joining two observations on the condition that they are at least 1 day apart.

Comment: You're right - I overlooked that because the example had one observation per month. Thanks!

Comment: Superfluous, sure there could be multiple rows per month. I see the comment of udden2903 and the comment is absolutely right. Thank you for noticing that. Can you please modify the code to account for that.

Comment: In the future, you should follow these guidelines when asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Still a little work remains to be done but this should work as a good starting point...

```
* First preping of data - eliminate rows that do not have dx411 nor dx430 ;
* and calculate time difference between rows of the same id) ;

data have;
  informat id 1. date mmddyy10. dx1-dx5 3.;
  format date yymmdd10. date_prev yymmdd10. delta_months 6.2;
  retain date_prev (.) id_prev (.);
  input id date dx1-dx5;
  array dx(5);

  if id = id_prev then 
    delta_months = intck("months", date_prev, date);

  dx_411 = 411 in dx;
  dx_430 = 430 in dx;

  if dx_411=1 or dx_430=1 then output;

  date_prev = date;
  id_prev = id;
  datalines;
1 1/1/2005 411 412 413 414 415 
1 2/2/2005 411 412 413 414 415
2 1/1/2006 411 412 413 418 419
2 3/3/2006 420 421 422 423 424
3 12/4/2006 430 510 520 530 560
3 3/4/2007 430 440 450 460 470
;
```

*Note that I have pre-sorted data so that older lines come first within an id group.*

**Identify and keep only id's showing on more than 1 row**

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select id, date, dx1, dx2, dx3, dx4, dx5,
           delta_months, dx_411, dx_430
      from have
     where id in (select id 
                    from have
                    group by id
                    having count(id) > 1);
quit;

proc print;run;
```

**Results**
[image: Resulting table]

**What remains to be done:**

- filter out rows/ids for which delta_months is above your threshold.
- filter out rows/ids that have, instead of 411-411 or 430-430, combinations 411-430 or 430-411. This could be done wither via proc sql or with a data step (incorporate it in the first one or in a subsequent independent one) using a retain statement. In this case-example, there were none of those.